# How to plot a repeated variable twice with ggplot2 (instead of it being coerced into a factor)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c('abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'bcd', 'abc', 'def'), Pos=c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5))

Name  Pos
abc   1
bcd   2
cde   3
bcd   2
abc   4
def   5
```

I want to plot the names in order of their position, but I want each row to appear, even if it's a duplicated value:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Pos, reorder(Name, -Pos))) +
    geom_jitter(width=0, height=0.05)
```

[image]

I can see that 'bcd' has two points at Pos 2, and 'abc' has a point at Pos 1 and 4. But I would like these to be on separate ticks on the y axis. If I change df$Name to a character instead of a factor (df$Name <- as.character(df$Name)), this doesn't help.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe create a new y axis variable with actual unique values, and then just modify the labels so some are repeated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds the row numbers to the data.frame, and plots with these, but assigns the Names as labels. Is this what you had in mind?

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Name=c('abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'bcd', 'abc', 'def'), Pos=c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5)) %>% 
  mutate(n = 1:n())

ggplot(df, aes(Pos, n)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = df$n, labels = df$Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this...?

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Name,Pos) %>% 
  mutate(Name1 = paste0(Name,row_number()))
labs <- with(df,setNames(as.character(Name),Name1))

ggplot(df, aes(Pos, reorder(Name1, -Pos))) +
  geom_jitter(width=0, height=0.05) + 
  scale_y_discrete(labels = labs)
```

[image]